# Cordova 3.5 iOS 8 Media Recording

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using the ionic framework to record audio using the Media object. It was working fine but with recent iOS updates now after recording something and releasing the Media object, the sound is disabled in my app until I crash it. No sound will play form any other part of the app and the + - volume controls on the side of the phone produce no volume overlay. I don't understand enough about iOS to know what's going on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881565/cordova-media-plugin-breaks-html5-audio-tag-on-ios That partially solved my problem, but if I record twice in a row it breaks again.

Comment: I eventually did figure that out when I was working on it, sheesh almost 2 years ago now. Should have posted the answer back then. THanks @Armando!